# Weblogic 12.1.2. "https + t3" combination on a single managed server. Is it possible?

Tags: ssl, weblogic, weblogic12c

WLS 12.1.2 is running under JDK 1.7_60 on Windows 7

To meet the requirement "Switch to HTTPS, but leave t3" the following steps are performed in admin console for managed server (where the apps reside)

- Disable default listen port 7280 (http and t3)
- Enable default SSL listen port 7282 (https and t3s)
- In order to enable t3, create a custom Channel

  - Protocol: t3
  - Port: 7280
  - “HTTP Enabled for This Protocol“ flag is set to false

After that, we have https and t3s on port 7282 and t3 only on port 7280.

In this case, we have issues with deployment of applications.
The deployer fails to start/stop the apps.
The reason is the deployer still tries to send messages to managed server via http.
I turned on the deployment debugging and see the following messages in admin server log.

```
…<DeploymentServiceTransportHttp> …<HTTPMessageSender: IOException: java.io.EOFException: Response had end of stream after 0 bytes when making a DeploymentServiceMsg request to URL: http://localhost:7280/bea_wls_deployment_internal/DeploymentService>


… <DeploymentServiceTransportHttp> …<sending message for id '-1' to 'my_srv' using URL 'http://localhost:7280' via http>
```

If I disable the custom t3 Channel, everything is ok. The deployer sends messages to https://localhost:7282, as expected. But in this case, we have no t3 available.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks